# Oracle returns empty data when searched via primary key

Tags: sql, oracle, select, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am getting a strange error while using Oracle SQL.

I can see data being there in a table but when i fetch it via command line using primary key, it returns empty set.

Table data is like

```
MERCHANT_ID | CUST_ID
------------|--------
200aksj000  | 123456
```

SQL:

```
SELECT * 
FROM MERCHANT 
WHERE MERCHANT_ID = '200aksj000';
```

It returns an empty set

Comment: Trailing spaces in the column? Try a like test instead? i.e. like '200aksj000%';

Comment: column size is varchar2(10). And like statement fails as well. Tried using sqldeveloper too.

Comment: Its strange, can you please try is once by altering the size of column to more than 10, just for testing.

Comment: Akshit - could you try to add a new record with MERCHANT_ID = '200aksj000' ?

Comment: Strange but increasing size to 11 did the trick

Comment: Are you sure you were querying it in the same session that inserted the data? Increasing the size to 11 means you ran some DDL which would have issued a COMMIT; then you would see the newly created data in another session.

Comment: I tried commit before also but didn't work. Changing size did. Let me recheck by decreasing size again.

Comment: Please, if using varchar columns then **always set them to a large length  (128 or 256)**. They only occupy the string length + 1 byte. imo, It is 'less than useful' to limit the length of them. If you want fixed length character fields, **and they must be fixed length as they get padded to the full length**, then specify them but trying to add one character longer will cause bother. imo, 1 or 2 character columns all other strings are varchar(256). why? the business rules may change to allow longer strings and I don't want to change the database column definition.

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. If the column was varchar2(10), how was it able to store the value '200aksj000'? That is 11 characters. It can't be stored in a varchar2(10) column no matter what you try. There must be something else you aren't telling us.

Comment: It was varchar2(10) as i can see in sqldeveloper. Also in data modeler its varchar2 (10 char).  Also in database now i get this problem in another table. There size of primary key is too big but it ain't searching with primary key